# Jenkins , How to connect with AWS repo?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, continuous-deployment

I am beginner in DevOps. Just started to work on DevOps.

So, I have to do continuous integration of Angular v5 setup in jenkins.

I have installed jenkins using WAR file and it is up and running.

While connecting with AWS repo, I am getting error.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNYEw.png]

What would be possible problem ?

Please guide.

Comment: 403 means forbidden. Did you try to configure git credentials (adding in Jenkins)?

Comment: I have configured using "aws configure" CLI option.  whether is it correct way ?

Comment: Did you install the aws credentials plugin and configured your aws secret key/access key so you can access the repo? (you probably configured it already on your local machine)

Comment: thanks for your guide , yes , i also installed aws credentials plugin , and now after adding username & password, it is looking fine.  
I have one doubt that I am running jenkins in my local. Whatever i will commit. will it be work or not ?

Comment: What will work? That jenkins will build your code? Yes it should work. You can also enable polling (jenkins checks every x time if there is a change on the repo, if there is, a build is triggered). You can not enable 'pushing'  (= when the repo receives a new commit --> tell jenkins: trigger a build) because your jenkins is running on your local machine and aws cannot access it.

Comment: @lvthillo, Thanks really helpful guide. It is working, automatic scheduling & build are happening from localhost.